# Who's the brown dinosaur in Braid?

Tags: braid

At the end of each world, there's a brown dinosaur who tells you that the princess is in another castle. I get the Mario reference, but is the brown dinosaur a reference to something else or is it a character original to Braid?

Comment: Hum. According to http://tig.wikia.com/wiki/Braid , Braid is influenced by a Commodore 64 game called Dino Eggs, but I can't find enough screenshots of this game (not a good keyword) to tell if there's a brown dinosaur in it.

Comment: There is a dinosaur in Dino eggs, but it doesn't seem the same to me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpoTwHAVd7w

Comment: It was actually an Apple II game ported to the C64. We had only a greenscreen at the time, so I couldn't say from experience whether or not there was brown anything in the game.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although David Hellman did most of the art for Braid, Edmund McMillen did some early character designs including the dinosaur<sup>[[1]](https://twitter.com/#!/davidhellman/status/179292736652980224)</sup>. You'll recognize Edmund's style from other gaming.SE favorites such as [Super Meat Boy](http://supermeatboy.com/) and [the Binding of Isaac](http://store.steampowered.com/app/113200/).

You can see the squat, tie-wearing style for Tim was kept from Edmund's [early](http://twitpic.com/6u9n2x) [drawings](http://twitpic.com/6u9nea), though David mentions that he redid the face for Tim. You can see variations on the Braid dino from Edmund [here](http://twitpic.com/6u9lkm). Edmund didn't mention any specific inspirations from other sources<sup>[[2]](https://twitter.com/#!/EdmundMcMillen/status/179330570898243585)</sup>; he's just a plush dino and one of his original creations for Braid.

Comment: Great, thanks! This looks like about as complete an answer as I could hope for.

Comment: I WANT THOSE DINOS AS PLUSHIES!

Comment: Congrats on successfully answering the highest voted unanswered question on the site!

Comment: @BenBrocka It called to me, so I asked around. Wasn't that hard to get a definitive answer from the source :)

Comment: Gotta love indie devs :)